# How to run an sql script in a kubernetes cluster for exactly for once

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

I have a service running on a Kubernetes cluster with many replications. My services are spring boot services.

I've no access to the DB, only the service does.

I need to run a script that alters schemas, it must be run once, and just before the newly deployed code starts running.

How can I run an SQL script exactly one time?

Comment: [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)  is a tool for migrating databases on application startup

Comment: yes I know I cannot use flyway either :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) for running a script. Init containers runs before the actual container runs.

Because init containers run to completion before any app containers start, init containers offer a mechanism to block or delay app container startup until a set of preconditions are met. Once preconditions are met, all of the app containers in a Pod can start in parallel.